# Que veut dire « rendre service comme tout le monde » dans cet extrait ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J'ai trouvé un article de blog [ici](https://ripostelaique.com/jai-refuse-laide-dun-jeune-arabe-qui-me-proposait-de-porter-ma-valise-pourquoi.html). Voici un extrait (l'autrice vient de dire qu'elle a refusé l'aide d'un jeune arabe) :

> Je me suis sentie triste et mal à l’aise. Parce que je n’ai pas su reconnaître un geste simplement humain, elle est là la vraie discrimination, non pas celle dont on nous parle constamment. Cet homme n’avait pas de mauvaises intentions, il voulait seulement m’aider, me rendre service. **Non pas comme tout le monde**, mais comme n’importe quel homme ou femme de bonne volonté. Comme il y en a certainement encore beaucoup.

Qu'est-ce que « non pas comme tout le monde » veut dire ? Habituellement, on ne rend pas de service à une femme qui n'est pas à même de porter sa valise dans un escalier ? Ou bien, ce jeune homme, l'arabe discriminé, voulait l'aider sans se sentir obligé de le faire, non pas « officiellement », pour ainsi dire, mais simplement comme un être humain ? Ou peut-être quelque chose d'autre, une troisième option ?

Merci beaucoup pour une explication !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Comme tout le monde*** est une locution. Faire comme tout le monde, c'est éviter de se démarquer, rester dans la norme sans originalité, sans en faire trop ni trop peu, comme la majorité des gens.

Ici, ***non pas comme tout le monde*** signifie que l'homme en question souhaitait sincèrement rendre service, et non pas aider la personne de manière machinale parce que la société attend cela de lui.

Comment: "Machinale" et "basique/baseline" ont peut-être la même idée dessous, mais tu le dis mieux. En tout cas c'est plus clair pour moi aussi maintenant. Merci !

Comment: In fact, this makes me reparse [« La serveuse automate »](https://mojim.com/usy131240x1x6.htm) a little, the first part of "J'ai pas envie d'faire comm' tout l'monde / Mais faut bien que j'paye mon loyer" being a fixed expression...

Answer (score 0):

À mon sens, « tout le monde » représente ici un point de comparaison, un niveau de sympathie qu'on ne reconnaît guère vu qu'on s'attend à ce que « tout le monde » la possède. Au-delà de cette sympathie basique se trouve « les hommes et femmes de bonne volonté », dont le jeune arabe.

Or je comprends votre difficulté à repérer la distinction que souhaite l'autrice entre ce « tout le monde » qui rendrait service à un étranger et « n'importe quel home ou femme de bonne volonté », mais comme elle juge bon de qualifier le deuxième genre de personne de « il y en a certainement encore beaucoup », on doit conclure qu'elle y en perçoit une.

Comment: Une fois, le 31 décembre de l'année précédente, j'ai proposé le même aide à une femme dans le métro de Pétérsbourg. Elle m'a répondu, « Mais vous, en réalité, ne souhaitez pas de m'aider, merci je vais faire tout par moi-même » (son expression était beaucoup plus simple, je ne m'en souviens pas). Et j'ai reconnu qu'il y a la différence. J'ai reconnu qu'il y a vraiment des gens qui le souhaitent et que je ne suis pas obligé de le simuler si je ne le suis pas…

Comment: @Evgeniy Merci, c'est intéressant.